# Cron Job sometimes "missed | Too late for the schedule" sometimes running

Tags: cron, magento2

**Sometimes Crons is working sometimes getting missed. I have attached all setting and result. Anyone can check and revert.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's completely normal behaviour. Some jobs are skipped caused the time frame is out of scheduled time for specified cron job. In your case the reindex process is scheduled every 1 minute. If there is more things to index (lot of changes on products, categories etc.) one minute is's not enough to complete. Also there is only one process per cron group, in your case `index`. `Use Separate Process` in cron configuration means that indexes process will run as separate process in relation to other cron groups.